# Light-box display error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a new site http://ww2.hawaiidiscount.com/ and everything works well except one feature. Click on one of the buttons "Book with Confidence". A light-box comes up but there is a scrolling feature that I cant figure out how to fix.

My light box css script is:

```
#cboxOverlay{background:url(images/overlay.png) repeat 0 0;}
#colorbox{outline:0;}
#cboxTopLeft{width:21px;height:21px;background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -101px 0;}
#cboxTopRight{width:21px;height:21px;background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -130px 0;}
#cboxBottomLeft{width:21px;height:21px;background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -101px -29px;}
#cboxBottomRight{width:21px;height:21px;background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -130px -29px;}
#cboxMiddleLeft{width:21px;background:url(images/controls.png) left top repeat-y;}
#cboxMiddleRight{width:21px;background:url(images/controls.png) right top repeat-y;}
#cboxTopCenter{height:21px;background:url(images/border.png) 0 0 repeat-x;}
#cboxBottomCenter{height:21px;background:url(images/border.png) 0 -29px repeat-x;}
#cboxContent{background:#fff;overflow:hidden;}
.cboxIframe{background:#fff;}
#cboxError{padding:50px;border:1px solid #ccc;}
#cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:28px;}
#cboxTitle{position:absolute;bottom:4px;left:0;text-align:center;width:100%;color:#949494;}
#cboxCurrent{position:absolute;bottom:4px;left:58px;color:#949494;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay{background:url(images/loading_background.png) no-repeat center center;}
#cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxSlideshow, #cboxClose{border:0;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:visible;width:auto;background:none;}
#cboxPrevious:active, #cboxNext:active, #cboxSlideshow:active, #cboxClose:active{outline:0;}
#cboxSlideshow{position:absolute;bottom:4px;right:30px;color:#0092ef;}
#cboxPrevious{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -75px 0;width:25px;height:25px;text-indent:-9999px;}
#cboxPrevious:hover{background-position:-75px -25px;}
#cboxNext{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:27px;background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -50px 0;width:25px;height:25px;text-indent:-9999px;}
#cboxNext:hover{background-position:-50px -25px;}
#cboxClose{position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -25px 0;width:25px;height:25px;text-indent:-9999px;}
#cboxClose:hover{background-position:-25px -25px;}
.cboxIE #cboxTopLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxTopCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxTopRight,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomRight,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleRight{filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);}
```

Comment: Please format your css so it will be readable.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS file (Mstyles.css) has this, which prevents lines from wrapping normally:

```
body {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you can't remove that for some reason, do something like this in your stylesheet:

```
div, p {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Update: Your `.page-container` class has exactly that on it, but your modal markup must be outside that element. You could simply move the modal markup inside `.page-container`.